# Creating a large textbox to get a paragraph input

Tags: java, html, jsp, textbox

I want to make an user enter a paragraph in a jsp page, but the problem is, the jsp page only displays a regular size text box , which is too small to enter a paragraph.

What i mean is i want to display a large text box in the jsp page so that the user can enter text in to it.

For example like this one :
[image]

How do i make a small text box as big as the above example?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use [textarea](http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/textarea/)

```
<textarea name="paragraph_text" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
```

#### Required Attributes

- **rows** is used to define the number of viewable rows.
- **cols** is used to specify the number of viewable columns.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can just right-click on the area of the website you're showing us and select "inspect". (You can do it even if you type on the textbox "Your Answer" in stackoverflow)
This way you will also know all css and javascript settings that give to such element the specific style you're looking at.
Works in all major browsers.
:P

[right click -> inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYLOl.png)

Answer (score 0):

use textarea

```html
<textarea  cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi @Subhojit - welcome to Stack Overflow.  Not sure if you noticed, but the accepted answer already provided this solution (with some information than you provided).  If you have something extra to add plese update the accepted answer with your new insights.